# Can Smart Contracts be used to execute trades on exchanges?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-design, wallet-transfer

I'd like to create a smart contract to execute trades on exchanges and transfer the received ethereum to another wallet. 
Something like this: 
* Receive token into wallet
* Smart contract sells token for ethereum
* Ethereum transfers to another address.

Is this possible?

Comment: If the exchange has a contract interface this is possible on-chain (you only need a contract for this). Something which comes to mind is direct interaction with EtherDelta or something similar. However, if you want to use a centralized exchange, you will need to transfer your tokens to the exchange (using their 'normal' address), run a script to sell tokens and then run another script to withdraw your ETH to an address. So in short it is possible but not only with contracts if exchange doesn't have an interface. Also keep withdraw fees in mind!